# How to create JSON response in PHP file?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'd like to get JSON response on my second server with the domain `example.com` where the `getit.php` file contains:

```
$arr = array('antwort' => 'jo');

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now when I try to get it with my first server:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/getit.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$antwort = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$antwort = json_decode($antwort);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($antwort);
    echo '</pre>';
```

I get:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["antwort"]=>
  string(4) "jo"
}
```

And not an normal array, how do I convert this to array?

I allready tried `$antwort = json_decode(json_encode($antwort), True);` but I only get a weird string with that?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the PHP function "json\_decode" return an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400651/why-does-the-php-function-json-decode-return-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON's definition is: JavaScript Object Notation. JavaScript arrays can only have numeric keys. Your array has string keys, therefore it MUST be encoded as a JavaScript **OJBECT**, which do allow string keys.

Tell json_decode() you want arrays instead:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
                          ^^^^
```

as per [the docs](http://php.net/json_decode)

Where how did you do your `json_decode(json_encode($antwort))`? The ONLY way that'd return a string is if you encoded the $antwort you'd gotten from `curl_exec()`.

Comment: @AnneSchwarz But why would you want an array over an object. Objects are even easier to deal with than arrays

Comment: how so? objects are only easier if you actually have a true object with methods and whatnot. an object just to store some keys/values is essentially IDENTICAL to an array.

Comment: Well I always worked with normal arrays and I think they are easier to read/handle

Comment: Haha I must admit I like the fact you have 2 less keystrokes to ref a property and the code looks cleaner. Anyway, arnt we supposed to be in an Obect Oriented World